# USe application.properties for OAuth

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

How to use propeties in application.properties in SpringBoot 2.0.0.M7 App?

I have foloowed the[documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/boot-features-security.html#boot-features-security-oauth2), but I dont know if I need to use OAuth2ClientProperties excplicitly

One more thing, the documentation doesn't according wih the autocompletion about 
syntax parameter

**my application.properies** :

> spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.verimi.authorization-uri=https://verimi.com/dipp/api/oauth/authorize
>   spring.security.oauth2.client.provid
>   spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.verimi.scope=login
>   spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.verimi.authorization-grant-typeer.verimi.tokenUri=https://verimi.com/dipp/api/oauth/token
>   spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.verimi.client-id=dipp
>   spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.verimi.clientSecret=G|41|0an18ZIs_w
>   spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.verimi.provider=verimi=authorization_code

**OAuthConfig** :

```
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Client
class OAuth2Config {

// What do I need to add ?

@Bean
    fun oauth2RestTemplate(oauth2ClientContext: OAuth2ClientContext,
                           details: OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails): :/* <--Error here : not bean found*/ OAuth2RestTemplate = OAuth2RestTemplate(details, oauth2ClientContext)
}
```

THX

Answer (score 0):

Verimi does not use plain OAuth2 but OpenID Connect which uses OAuth2 as authorization protocol. A few days ago I managed to make the official Verimi [Spring Boot sample](https://verimi.de/sdk-example) work. If this might help you I have pushed it in [Github](https://github.com/manios/verimi-sdk-spring-boot).